# Batch update not working in pgsql database laravel

Tags: laravel, batch-updates

I want to update data by batch that always goes to catch. I am using pgsql database.

I followed this tutorial
https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch

```
$tbc = $this->gradeService->updateGrade($request);
  try{
      if(count($tbc) > 0)
        \Batch::update('grades',$tbc,'id');
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return "OOps, an error occured";
    }

  return back()->with('status', 'Saved');
```

This part of code always execute catch. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Just a hint try printing the exception message `$e->getMessage() on $e->getLine()` hopefully it will be somewhere in your code

Comment: I will try this